# Javascript time selection like google analytics

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for a time range selector like the draggable google analytics time line section element.

Google provides the time line selection via a three block. This can be achieved with Jquery UI and many others. But the draggable timeline selection seems to be more difficult to achieve.

[ Shame about the image restriction for new users, perhaps someone could upload the image of google analytics time range selection via a draggable area ]

I do not want to use flash/flex for this and am looking for a javascript version. Im sure there is a javascript library out there but can not find it.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Highcharts master-detail example](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-master-detail/grid); the library uses jQuery and is pure JavaScript.

Comment: I am using high charts but the selection (although good) is not very accessible with regards to the multi option of calendar selection / draggable range with clear edges which can be grabbed and dragged.